# Don't allow click if any inputs with specific class are visible and have no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I ALERT and PREVENT users from clicking on any elements with the class `.popup_element` if any **VISIBLE** **INPUTS**  with class `.weight` have NO value

Below code is what I tried myself but doesn't seem to work.

```
    $(".popup_element").click(function() {  

        '' == $(".weight:visible").value && 

    alert("Please Select Value First.")
event.preventDefault();
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".popup_element").click(function(event) {  

    var foundNoValue = false;

    $(".weight:visible").each(function(){
        if($.trim($(this).val()) == "")
        {
            foundNoValue = true;
        }
    });

    if(foundNoValue){
        alert("Please Select Value First.")
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) to test for any blank values:

```
$(".popup_element").click(function() {
  if ($(".weight:visible").filter(function() { return this.value === ""; }).length > 0) { 
    alert("Please Select Value First.")
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

(If you need to treat nothing-but-spaces inputs as blank just use `this.value.trim() === ""`.)

I know I shouldn't really be encouraging your shortcut `&&` instead of `if` code, but if you want to do that you can have it run multiple statements by using parentheses and the comma operator:

```
$(".popup_element").click(function() {
  $("input").filter(function() { return this.value === ""; }).length && (
    alert("Please Select Value First."),
    event.preventDefault()
  );
});
```